# How does a discrete map (logistic map being only one such map) relate to a Poincare section?

Tags: chaos-theory

Basically the title. I am wondering if there is a relationship between the two, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Hi, welcome. You're expected to have done some minimal research of your own before resorting to posting here. For instance, is this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) enough to answer your question? If not, how so, what's still unclear?

Comment: @stafusa Hi. Yes, I have done minimal research. I know what these things are seperately, however, I just am not sure how they are related to each other.

Comment: From the Wikipedia entry: "a **Poincaré map** [...] is the intersection of a periodic orbit in the state space of a continuous dynamical system with a certain lower-dimensional subspace, called the Poincaré section, transversal to the flow of the system [...] One then creates a map to send the first point to the second, hence the name first recurrence map."